# Paypal not accepting payments on mobile device with credit card

Tags: paypal

When I use Paypal for checkout on my website, Paypal is showing checkout without Paypal account on Desktop but not on a mobile device.

Do you know could be the reason for this?

This is the form I use to redirect a user to the Paypal checkout page:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paypalForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="######@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Product X">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $orderKey; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="SolutionType" value="sole">
</form>
```

The form is being submitted by JS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using PayPal standard buttons, or ExpressCheckout, in some instances buyers will be able to pay with a debit/credit card and in some others they will only be able to open an account.
This can depend on many factors such as cookies, mobile/web, time of the day, and many other internal security variables which makes it impossible to predict. You could try to use the variable: solution_type = SOLE, it will give more chances to show the pay with card option but is not guaranteed.
If you wish to process card payments and you have a UK, USA or Canadian account you can think at PayPal Pro:
- for US / Canada, PayPal Payments Pro (https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro)
- for UK, PayPal Website Payments Pro (https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/pro)